# Android Date and Time Format

Tags: android, datetime

I have a sample date format **Tue, 23 Aug 2011 18:33:43 +0000**

In Android, I am using this statement **String now = new Date().toGMTString();**

And I am receiving this **23 Aug 2011 18:03:25 GMT**

What I need to do to get this format **Tue, 23 Aug 2011 18:33:43 +0000**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse and format dates.

Answer (score 4):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(yourDateInstance);
```

Comment: in other words, if I am on GMT+6 (+0600) but the server is on GMT (+0000) how can I switch date to GMT?

Comment: Simple solution, however, you should wrap in try-catch in order to avoid parseException

Answer (score 1):

Follow @MByD, except try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(yourDateInstance);
```